# print a view hierarchy on a device

Tags: android, android-layout

Debugging my app with strange results on Samsung phones, which I don't have physical access to. I'd like to ask a user to run an instrumented App to help debug. My App gets a `view` that has an unknown (to me ;-) hierarchy in it (`ViewGroups` etc). Is there a way to "walk" a `View` and print out to a string / `ddms` all the components in the `View` (etc `ViewGroups` in it etc)?

This would be akin to `HierarchyViewer` tool - if I had `adb` level access to the device.

Update: I guess I could use the method

```
void dumpViewHierarchyWithProperties(Context context, ViewGroup group, BufferedWriter out, int level)
```

from the `ViewDebug.java` Android OS sources ...

Anyone have a better idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here's the utility function I just made for this purpose:

```
public static void printViewHierarchy(ViewGroup vg, String prefix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = vg.getChildAt(i);
        String desc = prefix + " | " + "[" + i + "/" + (vg.getChildCount()-1) + "] "+ v.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + v.getId();
        Log.v("x", desc);

        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            printViewHierarchy((ViewGroup)v, desc);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would give +2 ups only for using $ in var names, i tought that was impossible, never tried.

Comment: I love this answer, but I would make it even better by using the following so that you can also print the id (if available):

`String desc = $prefix + " | " + "[" + i + "/" + ($vg.getChildCount()-1) + "] "+ v.getClass().getSimpleName();
      String id = null;
      try {
        id = v.getResources().getResourceName(v.getId());
      } catch (Exception e) {
        // no-op (no id found)
      }
desc += " " + (id == null ? v.getId() : id);
`

Answer (score 13):

I've created utility method which returns hierarchy in a pretty printed way with human readable view ids. Here is an example of the output:

```
[LinearLayout] no_id
  [CardView] com.example:id/card_view
    [RelativeLayout] no_id
      [LinearLayout] com.example:id/image_container
        [AppCompatImageView] com.example:id/incident_icon
        [CustomTextView] com.example:id/road_number
      [RelativeLayout] no_id
        [CustomTextView] com.example:id/distance_to_user
        [CustomTextView] com.example:id/obstruction_title
        [CustomTextView] com.example:id/road_direction
        [CustomTextView] com.example:id/obstruction_description
        [AppCompatImageView] com.example:id/security_related
```

Here is the utility method:

```
public static String getViewHierarchy(@NonNull View v) {
    StringBuilder desc = new StringBuilder();
    getViewHierarchy(v, desc, 0);
    return desc.toString();
}

private static void getViewHierarchy(View v, StringBuilder desc, int margin) {
    desc.append(getViewMessage(v, margin));
    if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
        margin++;
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v;
        for (int i = 0; i < vg.getChildCount(); i++) {
            getViewHierarchy(vg.getChildAt(i), desc, margin);
        }
    }
}

private static String getViewMessage(View v, int marginOffset) {
    String repeated = new String(new char[marginOffset]).replace("\0", "  ");
    try {
        String resourceId = v.getResources() != null ? (v.getId() > 0 ? v.getResources().getResourceName(v.getId()) : "no_id") : "no_resources";
        return repeated + "[" + v.getClass().getSimpleName() + "] " + resourceId + "\n";
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        return repeated + "[" + v.getClass().getSimpleName() + "] name_not_found\n";
    }
}
```

**Tip**: we use this method to add view hierarchies to some crash reports. **In some cases it is really helpful**.

Answer (score 1):

almost the same with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559520/print-a-view-hierarchy-on-a-device#answer-41723188) but with Kotlin:

```
fun getViewTree(root: ViewGroup): String{
    fun getViewDesc(v: View): String{
        val res = v.getResources()
        val id = v.getId()
        return "[${v::class.simpleName}]: " + when(true){
            res == null -> "no_resouces"
            id > 0 -> try{
                res.getResourceName(id)
            } catch(e: android.content.res.Resources.NotFoundException){
                "name_not_found"
            }
            else -> "no_id"
        }
    }

    val output = StringBuilder(getViewDesc(root))
    for(i in 0 until root.getChildCount()){
        val v = root.getChildAt(i)
        output.append("\n").append(
            if(v is ViewGroup){
                getViewTree(v).prependIndent("  ")
            } else{
                "  " + getViewDesc(v)
            }
        )
    }
    return output.toString()
}
```

Comment: this is how you print btw: `println(getViewTree(getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView() as ViewGroup))`

Answer (score 1):

The format of other outputs dissatisfied my eyes and some codes where an overhead. So, I improved the output with:

```
/**
 * Prints the view hierarchy.
 */
public static void printViewHierarchy(ViewGroup parent, String intent) {
    for (int i = 0, max = parent.getChildCount(), numLenght = (max + "").length(); i < max; i++) {
        View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        String childString = child.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + child.getId();
        String format = "|— %0" + numLenght + "d/%0" + numLenght + "d %s";
        Log.d("debug", intent + String.format(format, i + 1, max, childString));

        if (child instanceof ViewGroup)
            printViewHierarchy((ViewGroup) child, intent + "  ");
    }
}
```

to:

```
|— 1/4 ScrollView 2131296482
|— 2/4 MaterialTextView 2131296445
|— 3/4 FloatingActionButton 2131296374
|— 4/4 MaterialTextView 2131296363
|— 1/4 ScrollView 2131296482
  |— 1/1 LinearLayout 2129243036
    |— 01/74 RelativeLayout 2131296449
      |— 1/4 MaterialCheckBox 2131296332
      |— 2/4 MaterialTextView 2131296547
      |— 3/4 MaterialTextView 2131296531
      |— 4/4 AppCompatImageButton 2131296462
    |— 02/74 RelativeLayout 2131296449
      |— 1/4 MaterialCheckBox 2131296332
      |— 2/4 MaterialTextView 2131296547
      |— 3/4 MaterialTextView 2131296531
      |— 4/4 AppCompatImageButton 2131296462
    |— ...
    |— 74/74 RelativeLayout 2131296449
      |— 1/4 MaterialCheckBox 2131296332
      |— 2/4 MaterialTextView 2131296547
      |— 3/4 MaterialTextView 2131296531
      |— 4/4 AppCompatImageButton 2131296462
|— 2/4 MaterialTextView 2131296445
|— 3/4 FloatingActionButton 2131296374
|— 4/4 MaterialTextView 2131296363
```

Answer (score 0):

> These Views are not mine, they are coming from other Apps, so I cannot touch code related to them (I'm inflating them from a RemoteView)

If you are receiving a `RemoteViews`, and you are applying it to something in your activity, you have direct access to the resulting `Views`, no different than if you had inflated them from XML yourself. Given the root `View`, it is simply a matter of walking the children (probably depth-first, but that's your call) and logging whatever information you want.

Comment: That is actually what I did. What I was looking for is a class or library that provides this functionality "pre-canned". I availed myself of some code in the Android source for ViewDebug and basically did what you call out here.

Answer (score -1):

Just find menu item from BottomNavigationView and register long click.

```
View itemBag = bottomNavigationView.findViewById(R.id.action_bag);
    if (itemBag != null) {
      itemBag.setOnLongClickListener(BottomNavigationActivity.this::onLongClick);
    }

private boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
      case R.id.action_bag: {
        showToastMessage(R.string.menu_shopping_bag);
      }
      break;
    }
    return false;
  }
```